# How to count particular pattern in a string?

Tags: java, regex, scala

we have some requests which have a lot of experiments. I just want to count the no experiments. If it's greater than some number then I will block those requests

```
{
    "context": {
        "requestId": "",
        "locale": "",
        "deviceId": "",
        "currency": "",
        "memberId": 0,
        "cmsOrigin":,
        "experiments": {
            "forceByVariant":,
            "forceByExperiment": [
                {
                    "id": "test",
                    "variant": "A"
                }
            ]
        }        
}
```

In this request, I just want to check how many **id and variant** inside the **forceByExperiment**. I have tried to do using regular expression but not able to do it. Anyone do it before similar thing.

I just split the string with variant and count them. Not sure good idea, but the end goal is to figure out that the request have a lot of experiments.

Comment: Regular expressions are not a good fit here. Instead you'd need to parse the JSON (could be a generic structure of maps and lists) and extract the values from the parse result.

Comment: @Thomas I am not sure I got your answer right or not. you mean I should deserialize it to object. I have string json.

Comment: You should use a JSON library like circe or zio-json (or any other one you can find on google) to read the string into a `Map`-like structure, so you can actually traverse it and write something like `map("context")("experiments")("forceByExperiment").length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `circe` library and Scala, here is an easy solution:

```
import io.circe._, io.circe.parser._


val jsonString = """{
    "context": {
        "requestId": "",
        "locale": "",
        "deviceId": "",
        "currency": "",
        "memberId": 0,
        "cmsOrigin": "foo",
        "experiments": {
            "forceByVariant": [],
            "forceByExperiment": [
                {
                    "id": "test",
                    "variant": "A"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}"""

  

val parseResult = parse(jsonString)
val nElems = for {
  json <- parse(jsonString)
  array <- json.hcursor.downField("context").downField("experiments").downField("forceByExperiment").as[Seq[Json]]
} yield array.length

println(nElems) // Right(1)
```

Comment: I am not sure which one is good. In this case, we have to parse JSON. actually, I am trying to avoid this thing. But I think this solution is less error-prone as compared to a regular expression.

Comment: You should benchmark before concluding that the json parser will be slower than a regex.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use regex, and if there is no `id` field in your json structure, you can use the following expression `"id": "(\w+)"` and count the number of match.

Example: https://regex101.com/r/GCeByw/1/

Comment: It's not necessary to use regular expressions.  It's a string so I thought it's better to do with that. I don't want to deserialize it again in the object. yeah, I think I am looking at something you mentioned but can we break at runtime if the count exceeds some number.

Comment: @VimitDhawan as Thomas wrote you can count the number of matches or even extract the values and put them into a set and get the size of that set if you need to be able to count duplicates as 1. However, there's also a couple of conditions if you want to use regex, e.g.: 1) there must be no other `"id"` field in your structure, only those `"forceByExperiment"` elements. 2) The id's must not allow for escaped double quotes, 3) variants are not taken into account or must always appear directly after `"id"` (note that property order is not required in JSON).